# how to strip a string ignore case?

Tags: python

I am trying to strip the word "error:" from `error` variable,I want to strip of error:for all cases?how can I do that?

```
error = "ERROR:device not found"
#error = "error:device not found"
#error = "Error:device not found"
print error.strip('error:')
```

Comment: `strip` doesn't work the way you think it does, your example might produce the wrong results even with the correct case.

Comment: @MarkRansom - how do you strip error: irrespective of case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `re` module is probably your best bet:

```
re.sub('^error:', '', 'ERROR: device not found', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# '^error:' means the start of the string is error:
# '' means replace it with nothing
# 'ERROR: device not found' is your error string
# flags=re.IGNORECASE means this is a case insensitive search.

# In your case it would probably be this:
re.sub('^error:', '', error, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This will strip all variants of `ERROR:` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: `error:` can be anywhere in the string

Comment: @JeffShort you need to *assign* the result of `re.sub` back into `error`.

Comment: @JeffShort Then get rid of the `^`.

Comment: Thank for mentioning it. In case anyone is wondering, you can `$` at the string to find text at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression :

```
import re
error = "Error: this is an error: null"
print re.sub(r'^error:',"",error,count=1,flags=re.I).strip()
```

Result :

```
this is an error: null
```

#### Explanation

```
re.sub(pattern, replacement, inuputString, count=0, flags=0)
```

`pattern` is a regular expression, here we use a standard string prefixed with an `r` to specify that it is a regular expression.

`replacement` is what you want to be in place of the matches, an empty string to remove.

`inputString` is the string where you want to search, your error message.

`count` the number of occurence you want to replace, only one at the begginning.

`flags`: `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE` to match both "ERROR", "Error" and "error".

Answer (score -1):

you have the following variable:

```
error = "ERROR:device not found"
```

Now if you want to remove ERROR from it just remove the first 6 (if you also want to remove the : ) entries of your string. Like

```
error[6:]
```

which gives :

```
device not found
```

This command just takes entry 6 to : end of your string.
Hope this helps you. For sure this only works if error is at the begining of your string